# Setting dependency of a component to mantle-usl - custom Groovy class

Tags: gradle, moqui

I have a custom groovy class inside **mantle-usl** component. I would like to use the class in other component. Hence, I need to add a dependency so that the new component (or project) has the jar of mantle-usl ready for use.

Is there anyone who can help with this? I attempted to modify the build.gradle file of the project. And add a project dependency, but it returned an error.

```
project(':runtime/component/warehouse-items-masterenumerator') {
dependencies {
    compile project(':runtime/component/mantle-usl')
}
```

}

As you would expect, this does not work. It seems that I do not have the project references set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mantle-usl component doesn't have any compiled code in it so the build.gradle file does not build a jar file, it is only used for running the Spock tests.

I wouldn't recommend adding your own code to mantle-usl, it is easier and cleaner to put it in a separate component. For an example of a build.gradle file that does build a jar file look at the moqui/example component or most of the moqui tool components (such as moqui-elasticsearch).

You also don't need to modify the main build.gradle file from the moqui-framework repository, dependencies should be declared in the build.gradle file in each component (which are picked up automatically in the main build).